# Default arguments for structures

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a function defined like this:

`public static void ShowAbout(Point location, bool stripSystemAssemblies = false, bool reflectionOnly = false)`

This flags CA1026 "Replace method 'ShowAbout' with an overload that supplies all default arguments". I can't do `Point location = new Point(0, 0)` or `Point location = Point.Empty` because neither are compile time constants and therefore cannot be the default values for that function argument. So the question is, how does one go about specifying default argument values for structures? If it can't be done, likely I'll go for suppressing CA1026 in source with whatever justification someone here gives.

Comment: I say suppress the recommendation. It is definitely not gospel.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static void ShowAbout(Point location = new Point(), 
    bool stripSystemAssemblies = false,
    bool reflectionOnly = false)
```

From the C# 4 spec, section 10.6.1:

> The expression in a *default-argument*
>   must be one of the following:
>
> - a *constant-expression*
> - an expression of the form `new S()` where `S` is a value type
> - an expression of the form `default(S)` where `S` is a value type

So you could also use:

```
public static void ShowAbout(Point location = default(Point),
    bool stripSystemAssemblies = false,
    bool reflectionOnly = false)
```

EDIT: If you wanted to default to a value *other* than the point (0, 0), it's worth knowing about another trick:

```
public static void ShowAbout(Point? location = null
    bool stripSystemAssemblies = false,
    bool reflectionOnly = false)
{
    // Default to point (1, 1) instead.
    Point realLocation = location ?? new Point(1, 1);
    ...
}
```

This would also let callers explicitly say, "you pick the default" by passing in null.

Comment: I feel ridiculous for not trying the constructor with no parameters. I'll accept this answer in nine minutes.

Comment: You may want to consider `default(Point)`. To me it feels more intuitive.

Comment: All good suggestions. Of course, the rule still flags for a different version of the function that takes a `params string[]`, so I think CA1026 might be broken.

Comment: @Matthew: I think it's actually just that you're misinterpreting it :) See Daniel's post. It's possible that they just don't want you using optional parameters at all...

Comment: If that's the case I have every intention of disabling that rule. I've waited years to get default parameters so I can stop overloading functions a thousand times.

Comment: The "problem" with default parameters is that the values get compiled into the call site. So if you later change the default value, you'll have to recompile all the callers for them to notice. So you could argue that the warning should be changed to: "Consider the tradeoffs with default values".

Comment: @Daniel: It's definitely something to be aware of, but I'm looking forward to using optional parameters nonetheless :) In my situations everything's going to be recompiled together anyway. If you look at the bottom code snippet I provided, that gives another alternative - there, the *real* default value is computed at execution time; a null value acts as a sort of "compute the default value please" placeholder.

Comment: True. It is more of a problem with general library code. The default values have to be considered as part of the API (same with parameter names thanks to the new named parameters feature). So any change there has to considered the same way as other breaking changes in an API. If it is used only "internally", there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT CA1026 means you should replace it with functions that do not use default-arguments at all. So changing it as shown would still raise the violation.