# How to pass an Optional parameter that is a struct in C#

Tags: c#, struct, interop, pinvoke, optional-parameters

So I've run into this unfortunate situation where I have to, as the title says, write a function declaration with an optional `struct` parameter.

Here is the `struct`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
  public int nLength;
  public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
  public int bInheritHandle;
}
```

Here is the function in the .dll [`advapi.dll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724917(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
LONG WINAPI RegSaveKey(
_In_     HKEY                  hKey,
_In_     LPCTSTR               lpFile,
_In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes
);
```

Here's my declaration so far:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int RegSaveKey(UInt32 hKey, string lpFile, [optional parameter here!!] );
```

Comment: Is this of use; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676128/default-arguments-for-structures ?

Comment: I think you need to declare the last argument with  [Out, Optional] as shown here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13119

Comment: Declare a class instead of a struct.  Don't use `ref` in the pinvoke declaration.  Now you can pass `null`.  Alternatively, given that you rarely use this argument, just declare the argument as IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you should declare the 3rd argument as a `IntPtr`.
When you want to pass it null, give it `IntPtr.Zero`.
If you want to pass a real structure to it, `Marshal` the structure into memory - i.e. something like this

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
// set anything you want in the sa structure here

IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)));
try {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(sa, pnt, false)

    // call RegSaveKey here 
} finally {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
}
```